# highchart legend multiple position ? first legend left and 2nd legend right show in a chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, legend

**use high chart js multiply position legend**, I have 2 legends 1st legend align left and 2nd legend  align right, currently my view is (click the link and see ): **[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sayed021/2wfdesup/1/)** Or see below my code,  **how to possible this ?**

```
    yAxis: [
            {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                       return "$"+ this.value;
                    }
                  },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                opposite: false
            },
            {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                       return this.value + "k";
                    }
                  },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                opposite: true
            }
        ],
        legend:{
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            floating: true,
            symbolHeight: 50,
            itemMarginTop: 5,
            itemMarginBottom: 5,
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of the split legend: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/6gzp6tqu/

It's done by wrapping Highcharts `Legend.prototype.getAllItems` and `Chart.prototype.render` core functions. You'll find more information about wrapping here (***Wrapping prototype functions*** section): https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts